# Question about Linq

Tags: c#, linq

After reading the example of Microsoft [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397937.aspx#Y300)

```
        var query = from Student student in arrList
                    where student.Scores[0] > 95
                    select student;

        foreach (Student s in query)
            Console.WriteLine(s.LastName + ": " + s.Scores[0]);
```

I have a question :

Is it possible to avoid the loop ?

```
    foreach (Student s in query)
        Console.WriteLine(s.LastName + ": " + s.Scores[0]);
```

What if i rewrite the query and assume my query will always return one result.

```
    var query = from Student student in arrList
                where student.FirstName == "Cesar"
                select student;
```

I dont need to do a loop... I know that my query return only one element.

Comment: dont hesitate to edit my title. I don't know how to resume this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will still be an `IEnumerable`, but with one item. If you want to extract it you can use [First()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx) or even better [Single()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx):

```
var query = from Student student in arrList
            where student.FirstName == "Cesar"
            select student;

var student = query.Single();
```

Also you can replace the entire `where` clause by using `Single/First` overloaded methods:

```
var emperor = arrList.Single(s => s.FirstName == "Cesar");
```

`Single` is more strict than `First` since it will also check that there is exactly one item returned.

Comment: Maybe worth noting... if `arrList` is an in-memory collection that is known to contain unique values, `First` will give you better performance. After finding the first match, `Single` will check for another match which may, worst case, traverse the entire collection.

Answer (score 3):

FirstOrDefault, I prefer the method chain syntax, such as,

```
arrList.FirstOrDefault(s => s.FirstName == "Cesar");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from Student student in arrList
        where student.FirstName == "Cesar"
        select student;
```

use this  query.First().LastName

```
if (query.Count() > 0)
    Console.WriteLine(query.First().LastName + ": " + query.First().Scores[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FirstOrDefault() method.

Here's your query, re-written...

```
var student = (from Student student in arrList
               where student.FirstName == "Cesar"
               select student).FirstOrDefault();
```

Your query can also be written, chaining methods. In my opinion, it's easier on the eyes...

```
arrList.Where(student => student.FirstName == "Cesar").FirstOrDefault();
```

Or even more condensed...

```
arrList.FirstOrDefault(student => student.FirstName == "Cesar");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely avoid calling the loop, if you know that there is only going to be 1 record/object returned.

Have a look at the `.First()`, `.FirstOrDefault()`, `.Single()`, `SingleOrDefault()` extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

In the lambda way

```
 arrList.SingleOrDefault(q => q.Scores[0] > 95);
```

Answer (score 0):

For part 2 of your question, you can explicitly return a single Student object:

```
var student = (from Student s in arrList where s.FirstName == "Cesar" select student).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

query will be an `IEnumerable<Student>` in this instance.

`IEnumerable<T>` itself does not have an extension method that allows you to perform an action on each enumerated `T`, like for example, `List<T>` does with [`ForEach<T>(Action<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx). You can certainly write the extension method to do this and I am sure many people have, but it was a design decision to not have it (**[an article by Eric Lippert that discusses this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx)**).

If you know that your expression will always return one result then you can call `.First()` on the projected collection (assuming you know there will always be at least one result).

```
var query = (from Student student in arrList
             where student.Scores[0] > 95
             select student).First();

Console.WriteLine(query.LastName + ": " + query.Scores[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only one result will be returned can be dangerous.  What is more than one student scores over 95?

You can use a lambda expression, to compress your code:

```
arrList.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s.LastName + ": " + s.Scores.First());
```